# My dog has anxiety issues and I'm trying to discover the triggers

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have a 9 year old Lhasa Apso. Over the past year or two we've noticed that she goes into these weird states where she stands in out of character places in the house and shakes. It usually goes away after a few hours. We've spoken with the vet a few times and he hasn't been concerned enough to seek treatment.

Last week she got groomed and immediately after that she's been in the same depressed, trembling state for 5-6 days now. She's gone to the same groomer for years and they've always commented on how happy she was there. I took her to the vet yesterday and our first step is putting her in a Thundershirt. She seems to like it but it hasn't done much.

Her symptoms include trembling, acting depressed, not wanting to be alone, not being interest in treats, waiting somebody to sleep with her at night. The vet tested her urine and said it was perfect. She doesn't show any sign of physical pain.

I'm looking for ideas on how to identify the triggers for this. We haven't been able to find a pattern. There's no smoke detectors beeping. No fireworks. No loud music. No life changes. The kids have treated her normally. The next step is medication and I'd like to avoid that if possible because she doesn't act like this frequently enough to warrant it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this requires the expertise of a professional

Comment: Bring the vet video, if you haven't already done so. If the vet still thinks it's nothing serious and/or nothing treatable, either get a second opinion from another vet (bring the video) or accept the advice. Repeat until convinced one way or tthe other.

Comment: @keshlam I was satisfied with the vet's answer. I'm just looking for supplemental actions I can take in addition to the vet's recommendations.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would not associate "depressed" with the behavior you describe.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited the title.